# SSRS Pivot Columns

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to tackle pivoting my data in a way that captures duplicates, triplicates etc and places them into the proper column.   I want a count of the number of times a customer appears more than one time in my data set.  The number of times a customer appears more than 2x's, 3x's, etc.  And place those counts into the proper column.

I have tried numerous Count(iif(value, 1, Nothing))  configurations and can't get one to work.  Here is my latest stab that didn't result in what I wanted:

```
=Count(IIF(CountDistinct(Fields!Deposit_AcctNo.Value) > 1, 
Count(Fields!Deposit_AcctNo.Value), Nothing), "Accounts")
```

didn't work

=Count(IIF(Fields!Deposit_AcctNo.Value = 2, 1,Nothing))

didn't work

```
=CountDistinct(IIF(Fields!Deposit_AcctNo.Value = 2, 1,Nothing))
```

didn't work

```
=Count(IIF(Fields!Deposit_AcctNo.Value = 2, 
Count(Fields!Deposit_AcctNo.Value),Nothing))
```

didn't work

```
=Count(IIF(Fields!Deposit_AcctNo.Value = 2, 
Count(Fields!Deposit_AcctNo.Value),Nothing), "DataSet1")
```

didn't work

```
=count(IIF(CountDistinct(Fields!Deposit_AcctNo.Value) = 2, 1, Nothing))
```

Here is a pic of my desired outcome:

[image]

Comment: Remember, we have no context, just the text of your question. You'll need to provide more info or we could only resort to guessing at answers. Please try to include more code and sample data to help us create a repro of the problem you're facing. In addition, if you've tried numerous solutions, be sure to include (most of) them and explain why they didn't work.

Comment: fair enough, I would think the solution is trivial and I'm missing a simple piece of code to do this.  All the solutions are varying in nature of the Count(iif(   I have deleted them all each time I try to run the code and SSRS doesn't produce the result I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, I'd recommend working this out in SQL as I'm sure it's more efficient to aggregate counts there compared to using expressions in reporting services.

That said, here's how I would aggregate counts in reporting services:

Create a table with a single row group and group on the column with duplicates (customer account in your example, FirstName in my image below):

[image: Example table with one row group]

Use an expression like the following to count the number of times an item appears in the list (the second parameter for `Count` is the group name which will scope the aggregate function to groups).

```
=IIF(Count(Fields!FirstName.Value, "FirstNameGroup") = 2, 1, 0)
```

This should give you a table with a 1 or a 0 for each list item indicating which set the item falls in:

[image: Sample output using above expression]

Finally change the visibility of your row group to hidden, and add a totals row with a sum function wrapped around the original expression:

```
=Sum(IIF(Count(Fields!FirstName.Value, "FirstNameGroup") = 2, 1, 0))
```

Which should give you the output you're looking for:

[image: Sample output using totals and after hiding groups]

Comment: I tried literally EVERYTHING, EVERYTHING but the ") = 2, 1, 0) part on the outside of the code.  That seams to be it.  You have no idea how much of a headache this was.  I'd kiss you if I could